# Network Socket command

Tags: unix, netstat

Unix.....>>netstat -al | grep 8787 (will see packets on port 8787)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command

ifconfig -a

to determine the interface you want to listen on. Then use

tcpdump -npi eth0 port 8787

to listen on the port where eth0 is the interface you want to listen on that you identified from the ifconfig command.

Answer (score 1):

What is the nature of the question here? Are you trying to see packets on port 8787? Are you looking for services listening on port 8787? Most importantly, how is this a programming-related question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the actual packets then you need to use tcpdump.

Use the `-s` option to specify how much of the packet you want to see (`0` means the whole packet) and the `-X` option to get a Hex and ASCII dump.